# FlowLayout or BoxLayout? in JAVA

Tags: java, swing

I try to do this:

[image: Mokump]

but if I use GridLayout, the heigth is bery small

```
PanelPost.setLayout(new GridLayout(20, 1, 0, 12));
for(int y=0;y<15;y++){
            JPanel p=new JPanel();
            p.setBackground(Color.RED);
            p.setLayout(null);
            p.setSize(PanelPost.getWidth(),150);
            PanelPost.add(p);

        }
```

[image: GridLayout]
if I use FlowLayout, only displays some points 
With BoxLayout

```
setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

the panels are in the center and the width and height are not respected
and if i use setLayout(null) the scroll does not work then 
What is the best way to do this? :C

Comment: What's the problem with GridLayout?

Comment: Your problem starts here -> `p.setLayout(null);`.  `GridLayout` will use the preferredSize of the components to determine the cell sizes it wants to use.  This value is determine by the panel's layout manager...which you've now discarded...

Comment: With GridLayout  only displays lines because the height does no work, and p.setLayout(null) i use this because I put some Label and Panel inside this.

Comment: That's nice, use another layout manager or a series of layout managers, `null` layout is the cause of your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem starts here -> `p.setLayout(null);`.  `GridLayout` will use the preferredSize of the components to determine the cell sizes it wants to use.  This value is determine by the panel's layout manager...which you've now discarded...

Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

[image: Boo]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.Scrollable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(new ListOfStuffPane()));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ListOfStuffPane extends JPanel implements Scrollable {

        public ListOfStuffPane() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(20, 1, 0, 12));
            for (int y = 0; y < 15; y++) {
                JPanel p = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
                p.setBackground(Color.RED);
                p.add(new JLabel("Boo"));
                add(p);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
            return new Dimension(100, 200);
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
            return 128;
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
            return 128;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
            return false;
        }


    }

}
```

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Comment: :O i remove the setLayout(null) and works, but i will use your code Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use BoxLayout to solve this issue. Let me explain. First of all, let's consider your scenario; you want a scrollable list, right ? with components having fixed height, but varying width (since you had used the container's getWidth() as the width). So, for creating some thing "Scrollable", you need a ScrollPane in Java. JScrollPane is the preferred scrollable container. Now set this JScrollPane as the basecontainer. Now create a new JPanel object with the BoxLayout set as having Y_AXIS orientation. Now set this newly created JPanel object as the viewport of the JScrollPane container. So, by here, we had created a scrolling container.

Next step is what you mentioned in your code sample, ie adding 'post' elements. For that just as you did, inside the for loop create each JPanel objects. But instead of using setSize() method, you should use setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w,h)) method. This forces your components to render according to the dimension specified. For inserting vertical gaps between each post objects, you can use `java.awt.Box` class's createVerticalStrut(int height) method. I am giving the code  below. Feel free to ask if you have any doubt. :)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LinkedInLayout extends JFrame{
    public LinkedInLayout(){
        setTitle("Linked In Layout Resolution");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(0,0,500,520);

        JPanel postPane = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        JScrollPane container = new JScrollPane(postPane,ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        setContentPane(container);

        postPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(postPane,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        for(int y=0;y<15;y++){
            postPane.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(35));
            JPanel p=new JPanel();
            p.setBackground(new Color(247,221,221));
            p.setLayout(null);
            p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(postPane.getWidth(),75));
            postPane.add(p);
        }
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LinkedInLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't be concerned about the Class' name. I just gave it.

Comment: And if you wanna increase the Scrolling speed you can try this container.getHorizontalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(10);
container.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(10);